# Getting the next key from my SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table (I cannot change logic for various reasons) has a primary key which is of type `varchar(13)` with the structure like this:

```
Year+docType+number
```

with leading zeroes..

For example `21xxxx0000001` and so on.

There are many docTypes and many years.

The select for getting a last key for some const is like that:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @key = key 
FROM table WITH (RowLock Xlock) 
WHERE key LIKE @const + '%' 
ORDER BY key DESC
```

Is there any obvious better way?

---

A couple of clarifications:

1. this is a select from an application that is not mine, but I am working on some addon to add some features, and they are having problems with timeouts, problem being also in this select. Since my addon also uses their function to get a new key maybe I could use an alternative approach in my addon.
2. I don't know if ROWLOCK and XLOCK is good in this scenario, but select is used on a large scale, since it is many users, who create many documents.
3. last key is for example 21xxxx0000256, next key 21xxxx0000257
   or last=19yyyy0008956 and next = 19yyyy0008957.
4. @const is for example 19yyyy or 21xxxx, since we are searching for a last key of docType for some year.
5. there are many other columns on this table, also an identify field "id".

Comment: Define "last key" and "next key" relative to `docType` and `@const`, I don't understand, and your query does not seem to match with your description. Sample data and expected output would help. Also, why do you have `rowlock` and `xlock` hints, what do you think they are doing for you?

Comment: What is the value of `@const`? The issue with this key is that it isn't sortable by "last created" because it would be sorted by `Year` then by `docType`, then by `number`. So unless `@const` contains Year+docType, then you might have problems sorting. You may need to add other columns, such as an identity column, insert date column, or if you want multiple sources to have the ability to generate keys, you could consider using a `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: Short answer - no there is no "better" (which is undefined) way given the structure and a desire to avoid schema changes. Are you actually trying to solve a problem or is this more of a theoretical question? I hope you understand now why one column should not contain multiple elements.

Comment: @Charlieface I added some additional information. Sorry for bad formulation. 
So this query is used only to get the very last key for some docType and Year (const), for example const = '18yyyy'.

Comment: @ChadBaldwin I added some clarification in posts. Const is a year + doctype. In this case I can add some extra columns to the table, but the key must stay because it is a "system" field.

Comment: @SMor sorry, i added some more info to the post.

Comment: Given the constraint of not changing the existing table, no this is the best way. You would need an index on `(key)` to support this query though. Ideally you would split up the three parts into separate columns, and `number` would be an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` column. `ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK` hints would make more sense here